# error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError" when i do a update

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, sql-update

I want update my db with hibernate but i have this error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.create(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lnet/sf/cglib/proxy/MethodProxy;
```

Here is my method

```
public void update(Integer id, String question)
    {
        Session session = getSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try
        {

            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            Nodes node = (Nodes) session.get(Nodes.class, id);
            node.setQuestion(question);
            session.update(node);
            tx.commit();
        }
```

The error is here

```
Nodes node = (Nodes) session.get(Nodes.class, id);
```

I read on forums that it would be a cause of the jar, is this true?

thanks

Comment: Check your Hibernate version for the class Session and check if this method exists in this version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in my classpath i add the version 3 of hibernate. To me, this method exists, no?

Comment: According to Javadoc http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html , this method exists with the prototype.
But, as I write that, I review the error: this is a Proxy error, so an error with your code after it is encapsulated by an Hibernate Proxy. I do not remember Hibernate API, to help you I need to run in debug and I can not. I am sorry.

Comment: Ok thanks, for you the problem is the version of hibernate ?

Comment: Your hibernate version probably depends on a different cglib version. Check the dependencies for your hibernate version and see if cglib is compatible.